# How to get existing VPC cidr inside cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

creating cloudformation stack, which create additional subnet in vpc, i get VPCId (existing VPC) as parameter to stack. How to get VPC  cidr inside CF stack

Comment: For how to set and use parameters, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html#gettingstarted.templatebasics.parameters

Answer (score 5):

From [AWS::EC2::VPC - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html):

> `Fn::GetAtt` returns a value for a specified attribute of this type. The following are the available attributes and sample return values:
>
> `CidrBlock`: The set of IP addresses for the VPC. For example, 10.0.0.0/16.

However, I suspect this only works on a VPC that was created within the CloudFormation template.

Since you want to refer to an existing VPC, you will need to write a [CloudFormation custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) using AWS Lambda.

It's a bit tricky, but there are some good sample templates at: [stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources](https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Yes @John is right. You cannot use Fn:GetAtt on stack parameters as is given [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/looking-up-information-on-aws-cloudformation-stack-parameters-using-aws-lambda/) - "For resources created by CloudFormation, you can use the GetAtt intrinsic function to look up information. For stack parameters, you need a different approach."

Refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/looking-up-information-on-aws-cloudformation-stack-parameters-using-aws-lambda/) doc by AWS to know more about how you can get information about stack parameters.